# Bulk Loading Key-value pair data into HBASE

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata, nosql

I am evaluating HBASE for dealing with a very wide dataset with a variable number of columns per row. In its raw form, my data has a variable list of parameter names and values for each row. In its transformed form, it is available in key-value pairs.

I want to load this data into HBASE. It is very easy to translate my key-value pair processed data into individual "put" statements to get the data in. However I need to bulkload as I have 1000s of columns and millions of rows, leading to billions of individual key-value pairs, requiring billions of "put" statements. Also, the list of columns (a,b,c,d,...) is not fully known ahead of time. I investigated the following options so far:

- ***importtsv***: Cannot be used because that requires the data to be pivoted from rows to columns ahead of time, with a fixed set of known columns to import.
- ***HIVE to generate HFile***: This option too requires column names to be specified ahead of time and map each column in the hive table to a column in hbase.

My only option seems to be to parse a chunk of the data once, pivot it into a set of known columns, and bulk load that. This seems wasteful, as HBASE is going to blow it down into key-value pairs anyway. There really should be a simpler more efficient way of bulk loading the key value pairs?

**Raw data format:**

```
rowkey1, {a:a1, b:b1}
rowkey2, {a:a2, c:c2}
rowkey3, {a:a3, b:b3, c:c3, d:d3}
```

**processed Data format:**

```
rowkey1, a, a1
rowkey1, b, b1
rowkey2, a, a2
rowkey2, c, c2
rowkey3, a, a3
rowkey3, b, b3
rowkey3, c, c3
rowkey3, d, d3
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost assuredly want to use a customer M/R job + Incremental loading (aka bulk loading).

There general process will be:

1. Submit an M/R job that has been configured using `HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad`
2. Map over the raw data and write PUTs for HBase
3. Load the output of job into table using the following:

   sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -chown -R hbase:hbase /path/to/job/output

   sudo -u hbase hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles /path/to/job/output table-name-here

There are ways to do the load from java but it means impersonating HBase. The tricky part here is making sure that the files are owned by HBase and the user running the incremental load is also HBase. This [Cloudera Blog Post](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-hbase-bulk-loading-and-why/) talks a bit more about about those details.

In general I recommend taking a peek at this [GH Repo](https://github.com/jrkinley/hbase-bulk-import-example) which seems to cover the basics of the process.